# python remove command subprocess.call with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

I am trying to execute rm command from python in linux as follows

```
remove_command = [find_executable(
            "rm"), "-rf", "dist/", "python_skelton.egg-info", "build/", "other/*_generated.py"]
print('Removing build, dist, python_skelton.egg-
if subprocess.call(remove_command) != 0:
  sys.exit(-1)
```

The directories gets removed successfully but the regex pattern **other/*_generated.py**
does not remove the relevant **_generated.py** files.

How shall I remove those files using regex from python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work the way you intend it to, is that your pattern is not expanded, but interpreted as the litteral file name `"other/*_generated.py"`. This happens because you are relying on so-called [glob pattern expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

The glob pattern is typically expanded by the shell, but since you are calling the `rm` command without using the shell, you will not get this "automatically" done. I can see two obvious ways to handle this.

**Expand the glob before calling the `subprocess`**

This can be done, using the Python standard library `glob` implementation:

```
import glob

remove_command = [find_executable("rm"), "-rf", "dist/", "python_skelton.egg-info", 
                  "build/"] + glob.glob("other/*_generated.py")
subprocess.call(remove_command)
```

**Use the shell to expand the glob**

To do this, you need to pass `shell=True` to the `subprocess.call`. And, as always, when using the shell, we should pass the command as a single string and not a list:

```
remove_command = [find_executable("rm"), "-rf", "dist/", "python_skelton.egg-info", 
                  "build/", "other/*_generated.py"]
remove_command_string = " ".join(remove_command) # generate a string from list
subprocess.call(remove_command_string, shell=True)
```

Both of these approaches will work. Note that if you allow user input, you should avoid using `shell=True` though, as it is a security hole, that can be used to execute arbitrary commands. But, in the current use case, it seems to not be the case.